# Is there a LibreOffice equivalent to microsofts office themes?

Tags: libreoffice, compatibility, microsoft-office, presentation, productivity

I've used MS office for many years now. Especially powerpoint. One of the strengths is that it defines and separates the concepts of template and theme. A theme can be saved and contains fonts, colours, and a set of images that can be reused every time you create a new presentation. This ensures that everyone in your organization uses exactly the same colours and fonts all the time. Now I know that you can download templates for LibreOffice, but I have not seen anything similar to the theme concept. The file extensions used in MS office are the following for the two concepts mentioned:

- Example Powerpoint template file name: mytemplate.pptx
- Example Powerpoint theme file name: mytheme.thmx

Now back to my question: Do these concepts and their separation exist in LibreOffice or OpenOffice? If so, how do I create them?

Comment: They certainly exist (google 'odt templates'), but the information online is very unclear.

Comment: Try http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center and use the
Categories dropdown menu to select "Presentation templates."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

First create what you want your slide to look like, with the colours and fonts all correct. Then go to `File -> Templates -> Save`.

Give it a name, then click OK. The window will disappear. Then go to `File -> Templates -> Organize`.

A new window will open. Double click on the `My Templates` folder (on the left), then select by clicking the template you just made.

Click on `Commands -> Set as Default` Whenever you open a new LibreOffice Impress file, all the fonts / shapes / colours that you've set just now will be configured.

If you then send these instructions, along with the Impress template (saved in /home/USERNAME/Templates) to everyone else who need the style, you will all be using the same one.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will try that. The way I see it: what you describe is the very nature of a template. But I fail to see how a theme has it's own concept in this picture. The great thing with the theme concept is that you can take an already made presentation and apply a different theme (while keeping the same template). In this way you can easily switch the "brand" of the same presentation.